# Syntax to load nested in nested keys of JSON files

Tags: python, json

I have a big tree in a JSON file and I'm searching the python syntax for loading nested in nested keys from this JSON.
Assume I have this :

```
{
  "FireWall": {
    "eth0": {
      "INPUT": {
        "PING": 1,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the man page and some questions in Stackoverflow i tried this (and some variations) :

```
import json

config = open('config.json', 'r')
data = json.load('config')
config.close()

if data['{"FireWall", {"eth0", {"INPUT", {"Ping"}}}}'] == 1:
    print('This is working')
```

With no result. What is the right way to do this (as simple as possible) ? Thank you !

Comment: It should be `data = json.load(config)`

Comment: You will have an error on `json.load` because you need to pass the *object* `config`, not the `str` `'config'`

Comment: Thank a lot tobias_k and C.Nivs that was the missed point, this is workging ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying `data = json.load('config')` to load  string not file object and `data['{"FireWall", {"eth0", {"INPUT", {"Ping"}}}}']` it's not right way to access nested dictionary key value.

```
import json
with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

if data["FireWall"]["eth0"]["INPUT"]["Ping"] == 1:
    print('This is working')
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a nested dictionary, so:

```
data["FireWall"]["eth0"]["INPUT"]["Ping"]
```

will be equal to 1; or at least it will when you fix your call to `json.load`.

Comment: Thank for your reply I already tried this but I got a     return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Why don't you include _how_ to fix that other problem, too?

Comment: Because it wasn't asked for?

Comment: So if someone on the street asks you for directions while his hat is on fire you point him in the right direction and move on?

Comment: If he *knows* his hat is on fire, I'll trust his judgement.  If OP is getting an error message, *can't bother to post it*, and asks about something else, I'll trust that judgement too.

Comment: Granted, in my example saying "Oh, and maybe you should also fix your hat..." should be enough, but OP seems to be rather new to both Python and this site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data["FireWall"]["eth0"]["INPUT"]["PING"]
```

This will give you the value in PING

Comment: With this i have an error : ``return loads(fp.read(), AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'``